# Why "TextWrapping" automatically add to XAML when TextBox inserted

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

After Drag/Drop some control like TextBox in a WPF Window, you can see below line in XAML

```
<TextBox ... TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" />
```

These properties automatically insert to XAML!
Just some special property inserted in XAML.

## Questions:

- Why just these special properties (like `TextWrapping` or `Text` for TextBox) automatically add in XAML? (Is there a kind of Attribute for this)?
- I want to inherit a class from TextBox and prevent of automatic insertion of `TextWrapping` property. Is it Possible? (Is there a kind of Attribute for this)?
- Is there a solution, to select some properties for automatic inserted in XAML, in design mode (like this `TextWrapping` TextBox)?

Comment: What version of VS are you using?

Comment: @Jim: Currently i'm using VS.Ultimate.2012.Update1 but these are WPF Control features and not related to VS, I can remember this ability from VS2008 till now. Some UI Controls have these abilities which inserted some properties value to XAML (after insert in design mode) and this is not related to STYLE or DEFAULT VALUE. Thank you for your trying to help ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is the [DefaultInitializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.design.model.defaultinitializer.aspx) that defines what defaults are set when dragging from the ToolBox onto the design view.

```
[Feature(typeof(myDefaults))]
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class myDefaults : DefaultInitializer
    {
        public override void InitializeDefaults(ModelItem item)
        {
            item.Name = "test";
        }
    }
}
```

Then dragging and dropping this control on the form results in

```
<local:UserControl1 x:Name="test" Width="100"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

To set default values for wpf controls (like you want all your TextBoxes to be 30 pixels wide by 10 pixels tall with a 5 pixel margin) you can define styles.

If you look at the sample provided here, you can see how a default TextBlock style is defined and applied to all TextBlocks.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx

```
<!--A Style that affects all TextBlocks-->
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
  <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
  <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS"/>
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
</Style>
```

If you did want more of a designer experience I'd recommend using Blend instead of the Visual Studio Designer.

Comment: This is totally not related to STYLE or DEFAULT VALUE and my question :( 

Some Element (like TextBox) after Drag/Drop in design mode, initiate a custom values for some properties with automatic insertion values in XAML. For Example: `TextBox`>`TextWrapping` has `NoWrap` as default value BUT after Drag/Drop insert some code (in design mode) which `TextBox`>`TextWrapping` is `Wrap`. I develop a Custom UIElement (User Control) and i need to have a feature like this. A automatic insertion some value for some properties.

Comment: What you are explaining sounds like the default behavior for Visual Studio and WPF elements.  I think making a style and then sharing that across your project is an easier solution than creating a custom uielement.  

However, if you have good reasons for creating the custom uielement, this post might help you.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1ce1184a-7b8c-40d1-ad52-71b2a6c9b3b6/wpf-designertoolbox-default-values.  

It sounds like you need to use a DefaultInitializer for your custom control.

Comment: This is wrong. Default property values from a Style or property metadata have nothing to do with the XAML that is generated when an element is dropped from the toolbox into the XAML designer.