# How to generate xamlmarkup for properties of a custom control?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am developing a custom control library using WPF in VS2010.It is a chart control like `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart`.

When the Chart Control provided by MS is dragged from the toolbox and dropped into the VS XAML designer , the xaml markup is generated for the Chart Control, along with the xaml markup for the property ‘Series’(‘Series’ is a content property) of Chart Control.

I was wondering how this is implemented .In another word, how can I generate xamlmarkup with attribute set for properties of a custom control when dragged from the toolbox and dropped into the xaml designer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why "TextWrapping" automatically add to XAML when TextBox inserted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261173/why-textwrapping-automatically-add-to-xaml-when-textbox-inserted)

Comment: Yes,you are right,Shoe.It really helps me out.You are a good man.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to pull down the SDK but here are some links on MSDN to get started:

- [How to: Create a Toolbox Control That Uses WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee712574.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Creating a WPF Toolbox Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee712573.aspx)
- [Control Authoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms745025.aspx).

Comment: Sorry,OmegaMan,it could not solve the problem,but thank you all the same.